# Tkinter frame with opengl

Tags: python, opengl, tkinter, pyopengl, opengl-compat

I am trying to draw a square with opengl using tkinter frame but the square didn't render.

Here is my code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from opengl.gl import *

from pyopengltk import OpenGLFrame

class frame(OpenGLFrame):

    def initgl(self):
        glViewport(0.0,self.width,self.height)
        glClearColor(0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0)
        
    def redraw(self):

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER)

        glLoadIdentity()

        glBegin(GL_LINES)
        glColor3f(1.0,0.0,3.0)
        glVertex2f(200,100)
        glVertex2f(100,100)
        glEnd()
        gl_Flush()

if __name__=='__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()
    app = frame(root,width=500,height=500)
    app.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.YES)
    app.mainloop()
```

I got no error expect the green screen without no lines drawn.

This is the image of the codes result it shows no error but the lines didn't show:

[image]

Comment: There is a typo. `glViewport` has 4 arguments. It has to be `glViewport(0, 0, self.width, self.height)` rather than `glViewport(0.0,self.width,self.height)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line does not render, because you don't setup an [Orthographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection). If you don't set an orthographic projection, then you have to specify the coordinates in normalized device space. NDC are a unique cube, with the left, bottom, near of (-1, -1, -1) and the right, top, far of (1, 1, 1).

Specify an orthographic `GL_PROJECTION` matrix (see [`glMatrixMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml) ) by [`glOrtho`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glOrtho.xml), that maps the window coordinates to NDC:

```py
class frame(OpenGLFrame):

    def initgl(self):
        glViewport(0, 0, self.width, self.height)
        glClearColor(0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0)

        # setup projection matrix
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
        glLoadIdentity()
        glOrtho(0, self.width, self.height, 0, -1, 1)

        # setup identity model view matrix
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
        glLoadIdentity()

        
    def redraw(self):

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        glLoadIdentity()

        glBegin(GL_LINES)
        glColor3f(1.0,0.0,3.0)
        glVertex2f(200,100)
        glVertex2f(100,100)
        glEnd()
        glFlush()
```

Comment: Rabbid76 pls can you write code to render a wireframe cube for me your codes only works for 2d when I add 3d coord it didn't show

Comment: @Lord_daniel You have to ensure that the geometry is in between the near and far plane, else the geometry is clipped. In your case the near plane is -1 and the fare plane 1 (`glOrtho(..., -1, 1)`). Increase that range. Anyway, if you have a question, then [Ask a public question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). the comment section is not intended to ask questions.